# cpanel cron job command syntax

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am trying to set a cron job on cpanel to run every minute all the time. in the command, I have written

```
php /home/hallsamc/public_html/reverse_booking.php
```

but it still does not execute the script. when I load the file from the browser, it works as expected but the cron job does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use following syntax and let me know.

```
php -q /home/hallsamc/public_html/reverse_booking.php
```